# SharedPreferences no persiste los datos al cambiar de Activity usando generics

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Empecé a usar Sharedpreferences con una clase específica para leer/escribir y funcionaba correctamente, persistian los datos al cambiar de actividad y salir de la aplicación. Pero cuando a aquella clase le implementé generics al intentar cambiar de actividad o al salir de la aplicación no quedan persistidos los datos en sharedpreferences. No es que no se guardan porque puedo visualizarlos con el método de read siempre y cuando no salga de la actividad o de la app. Creo que tiene que algo con el uso del TypeToken, al no poder crear uno genérico creo uno en base a mi lista específica y lo mando por parámetro, puede ser que al crear siempre uno nuevo sea el causante de que no se guarden correctamente los datos? Si es el caso cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Mi clase para leer/escribir en sharedpreferences

```
public class PrefConfig extends Application {

    public static <T> void writeListInPref(Context context, ArrayList<T> list, String key) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(list);
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(key, jsonString).apply();
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static <T> ArrayList<T> readListFromPref(Context context, String key, Type type) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String jsonString = pref.getString(key, "");
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        return gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
    }
}
```

Usando los métodos

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Libro>>() {}.getType();
libros = PrefConfig.readListFromPref(getContext(), "libros", type);
if(libros == null) {
      libros = new ArrayList<Libro>();
      PrefConfig.writeListInPref(getContext(), libros, "libros");
      }
```

Comment: Hola! Creo que deberias usar una base de datos para guardar listas, SharedPreferences como esta diseñado y orientado, son para datos de usuario como un nombre, apellido. Pero para listas y objetos mas grandes recomendaría usar un base de datos. Room por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion seria guardar el listado de libros en un archivo local.
Debido a que el sharedpreferences es solo para guardar elementos relacionados con la configuración.
La implementación del preference está bien, pero te va a reescribir el objeto libro.

Crea un metodo para almacenar el json  y despues leerlo.

Aca va un ejemplo de como guardar el json.

```
    public boolean guardarJson(JSONArray array,String archivo)  {
       FileOutputStream outputStream;
       try {
          outputStream = mContext.openFileOutput(archivo,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          outputStream.write(array.toString().getBytes());
          outputStream.close();
          return true;
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return false;
    }
```

En este ejemplo se ve como guardar un jsonarray